# React on Github Pages: gh-pages package not working

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, windows-10, github-pages

## Problem

I am trying to put my React app on github pages. However, I can't even deploy the app to GitHub pages.

## My Setup

I am using Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10 machine. I created my React app with *create-react-app*. I followed [this tutorial to set up my app for Github Pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages). This is my *package.json*:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://MisturDust319.github.io/ign_code_foo",
  "name": "ign_code_foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy:": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

The full source is available [here](https://github.com/MisturDust319/ign_code_foo)

## What I've Done

To deploy, you are supposed to just run

```
npm run deploy
```

However, when I enter that command, from Windows PowerShell, Git Bash, and the Command Prompt, I just get several variations of "command not found".

In response, I uninstalled *gh-pages* from dev-dependencies and reinstalled it as a normal dependency. No change. At this point, I've exhausted all solutions I can think of, and Google has only pulled up people who didn't include the *deploy* command in package.json.

Comment: What does it say exactly? When you run the command.

Comment: bash: gh-pages: command not found

Comment: Are you sure `gh-pages` is actually installed or it only is on your `package.json`? Try `npm install` first

Comment: I had the same problem and found running `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` again fixed it

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. I've installed `gh-pages` multiple times with the `--save-dev` flag and I've restarted my terminal but it is still not recognizing this command. 

Answer (score 20):

You need to install gh-pages globally by adding "-g":

```
npm install -g gh-pages --save-dev
```

and then

```
npm run deploy
```

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally

Comment: page not found in your link

Comment: You should never globally install things that are referenced within a project. It's the root of all "works on my machine" issues, as anyone else who checks out the repo doesn't have all of the necessary dependencies to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You need install gh-pages before running deploy, run:

`npm install --save-dev gh-pages` 
then
`npm run deploy`

Comment: He has it in `package.json`

Answer (score 4):

I cannot add a comment to this post, because I don't have enough score. But there is an error in the your *package.json* code:

```
 "deploy:": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Because, there is an extra semicolon `:`. It should be:

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Answer (score 1):

Little explanation about why this issue is happening ,followed by the fix of this issue

In package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {  
    "gh": "^2.8.6",  
    "pages": "0.0.16"  
  }
```

gets created when we run **npm install gh pages —save-dev**
but to deploy our project when we run **npm run deploy** that time it checks in package.json file against **deploy** which script is mentioned

Since in package.json

```
"scripts": {  
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",  
....}
```

**gh-pages -d build** script is mentioned.
It will try to perform this operation but the reason its throwing error like this( if you are mac user) on npm run deploy

```
sh: gh-pages: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! basic@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the basic@0.1.0 deploy script.
```

is because gh-pages also need to be installed globally as well.
So if you run **npm install -g gh-pages --save-dev**
Issue which you're getting related to gh-pages installation will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a path problem, it's a usual case for Windows users that try to use cmd instead of *nix terminal. Try to exit and enter cmd if you didn't yet. After that you should ensure that it can access `gh-pages` package.

Also you might look on answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150250/gh-pages-failing-while-trying-to-deploy-reactjs-app-to-github-in-windows-10). And ensure that your git version is >= 1.9 as it's told in [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150250/gh-pages-failing-while-trying-to-deploy-reactjs-app-to-github-in-windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

I had copied items into the wrong section. In my case my `dependencies` are above the `scripts` and I had put two scripts in the `dependencies` section like a money. Moving them into the right place resolved the issue for me.

Tip: make sure your script are not placed in the wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

**Very, very** likely you don't have `git` added to your `Path` variable

If running `git` in your `CMD` results in an error - this is the issue.

Add `git.exe` and other binaries to your path, usually it `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and try again running `gh-pages -d build`

Answer (score 0):

i had to set private to false at package.json